# error en aceptar unicode en django-python 2.7.1o

Tags: mysql, python, django, python-2.7

Buenos dias para todos. El error que sale es el siguiente:

En este momento estoy intentato conectar la base de datos con django utilizando mysql y la version de python 2.7.10 al momento de utilizar python manage.py makemigrations en el termina es el siguiente:

```
Microsoft Windows [Versión 10.0.10586]
(c) 2015 Microsoft Corporation. Todos los derechos reservados.

C:\Users\Aprendiz Sena\Desktop\jazmines3-master>manage.py makemigrations
'import sitecustomize' failed; use -v for traceback
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\Aprendiz Sena\Desktop\jazmines3-master\manage.py", line 10, in <module>
    execute_from_command_line(sys.argv)
  File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\django\core\management\__init__.py", line 338, in execute_from_command_line
    utility.execute()
  File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\django\core\management\__init__.py", line 303, in execute
    settings.INSTALLED_APPS
  File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\django\conf\__init__.py", line 48, in __getattr__
    self._setup(name)
  File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\django\conf\__init__.py", line 44, in _setup
    self._wrapped = Settings(settings_module)
  File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\django\conf\__init__.py", line 92, in __init__
    mod = importlib.import_module(self.SETTINGS_MODULE)
  File "C:\Python27\lib\importlib\__init__.py", line 37, in import_module
    __import__(name)
  File "C:\Users\Aprendiz Sena\Desktop\jazmines3-master\exequiales\settings.py", line 16, in <module>
    import sitecustomize
  File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\sitecustomize.py", line 2, in <module>
    sys.setdefaultencoding("UTF-8")
AttributeError: 'module' object has no attribute 'setdefaultencoding'

C:\Users\Aprendiz Sena\Desktop\jazmines3-master>
```

> No se si sea por el sistema operativo windows, o me falten paquetes o
>   algo parecido en este caso los paquetes instalados son los siguientes:

```
Django  1.8 2.0rc1
MySQL-python    1.2.5   1.2.5
Pillow  4.3.0   4.3.0
PyJWT   1.5.0   1.5.3
PyMySQL 0.7.11  0.7.11
asn1crypto  0.22.0  0.23.0
certifi 2017.4.17   2017.11.5
cffi    1.10.0  1.11.2
chardet 3.0.4   3.0.4
cryptography    2.0 2.1.4
django-bootstrap-form   3.3 3.3
django-contrib-comments 1.8.0   1.8.0
django-mysql-pymysql    0.1 0.1
enum34  1.1.6   1.1.6
idna    2.5 2.6
ipaddress   1.0.18  1.0.18
mysql   0.0.1   0.0.2
mysql-connector-python  8.0.5   8.0.5
numpy   1.13.3  1.13.3
olefile 0.44    0.44
pip 9.0.1   9.0.1
pyOpenSSL   17.1.0  17.5.0
pycparser   2.18    2.18
pytz    2017.2  2017.3
requests    2.18.1  2.18.4
setuptools  36.2.0  38.2.4
six 1.10.0  1.11.0
twilio  6.4.3   6.9.1
urllib3 1.21.1  1.22
wheel   0.30.0  0.30.0a0
```

> y el settings de la base de datos esta asi:

```
DATABASES = {
    'default': {
        'ENGINE': 'django.db.backends.mysql',
        'NAME': 'jazmines',
        'USER': 'root',
        'PASSWORD': 'root',
        'PORT': '3306',

    }
```

> el sitecustomize.py para codificar en utf-8 es el siguiente:

```
import sys
sys.setdefaultencoding("UTF-8")

import io
io.open(filename, encoding='latin-1')
```

Answer (score 0):

El problema es causado por `setdefaultencoding()`, python elimina la referencia de esta funcion despues de su inicialización, por ello tiene ese error.

Una posible solucion es usar reload():

```
import sys
# sys.setdefaultencoding() fue removido aqui
reload(sys)  # se recarga para habilitarlo devuelta
sys.setdefaultencoding('UTF-8')
```

Sin embargo, esto no es algo seguro de hacer: esto es obviamente un truco, ya que `sys.setdefaultencoding()` se elimina intencionalmente de sys cuando se inicia Python. Al volver a activarlo y cambiar la codificación predeterminada, se puede descifrar el código que depende de que ASCII sea el predeterminado (este código puede ser de terceros, lo que generalmente haría que arreglarlo sea imposible o peligroso).